# How can I store /var on a separate partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I'd like to store `/var` on a separate partition from `/`. What is the correct way to set this up?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First prepare a new partition (e.g. with `parted` and `mkfs`).

Say the partition is /dev/sda5

Mount the new partition:

```
mkdir /var2
mount /dev/sda5 /var2
```

Sync your current var:

```
rsync -a /var/ /var2
```

Add the entry to /etc/fstab

```
/dev/sda5    /var    ext4    defaults      2 2
```

Reboot.

If you happen to need to go back you your old /var just comment out the entry in fstab.

Comment: I would add some information to recover the space on the old `/var`: start from a livecd, mount the partition on the installed system `/` and `rm -rf /var/*`.

Comment: Good point. Or you can mount `/` to some other location on the current system while it's running (but after rebooting). Then you can get at the old `/var` and delete it if you like

Comment: @Aleksandr I've made a minor correction to your rsync command, but I don't understand why you suggest `1 1` in fstab. Can you please explain this?

Comment: @Aleksandr Levchuk - Yes, this intrigues me too.

Comment: I used to wonder about those too. The first 1 is something really archaic and effect-less, the second one controls the order of fsck's when it's time to scan your ext during boot. I don't pay attention to them anymore. Just put 1 1 because the syntax requires it.

Comment: You should put 2 2 to let things like / get fsck scan before /var when you reboot the 30th time. Otherwise if /var fails and asks you to fix things manually in a single user shell - then you will not have any filesystem. Fun stuff.

Comment: Isn't the recommendation to use UUIDs in fstab? I got the appropriate one using `blkid -o list -s UUID`, but I think you need to run with sudo

Comment: I definitively will go with UUID, as it makes safe and reliable to attach drives later, if you change HDD drives ordering, using sdx will surely break your OS

Comment: Make sure to remember this by heart: __sudo blkid -p__. This option can save you many headaches - trust me. For instance, trying to retrieve a UUID from `blkid` after it was changed (by `tune2fs`, `gparted` etc.) is *very* prone to doing something wrong. I had the same problem: my system did not boot any more. Reason: `blkid` read and printed the __old__ UUID from the cache! (And as I don't know how to flush the cache, I use `blkid -p` (superuser only)).

Comment: The `rsync` command should be `rsync -aAX` so that this still works if selinux is enabled.

Answer (score 4):

## Configuring a new /var partition on a virtual server

When I took over a new virtual server that had been provisioned by my employer’s hosting company, there wasn’t enough free space in the root filesystem. Luckily, they had used [Logical Volume Manager (LVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) to sub-divide the virtual disk and there was sufficient free space available to create new volumes.  I created extra logical volumes for `var` and `home` which had been regular directories in the root filesystem. Since the virtual server provider didn’t provide a KVM-like interface by which I could access the server in single-user mode, I used a very similar method to the one outlined by Aleksander (this answer includes extra details for recovering disk space in addition to LVM-specific commands).

### Create a new /var filesystem with LVM

Create a logical volume for the new `var` filesystem, mount it (using a temporary directory) and copy files from the current `/var` to the new filesystem:

```
# Create a new 60GB logical volume in the `VolGroup00` group called `var`.
sudo lvcreate -L 60GB -n var VolGroup00
# Create an ext4 filesystem on this new `var` volume.
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/VolGroup00/var
# Mount this filesystem at a temporary mount-point.
sudo mkdir /var.new
sudo mount /dev/VolGroup00/var /var.new
```

Since running processes will have files in `/var` kept open and in use, the directory tree can’t simply be moved to the new filesystem.  Recursively (`-r`) copy files from the current `/var` partition to the new filesystem while preserving file attributes and extended attributes (`-a, --archive` option). A cautious user might first create an [LVM snapshot](https://askubuntu.com/q/424225/93375) of the current volume before copying but that’s too much off-topic detail for this question.

```
sudo cp -ra /var/ /var.new/
```

Alternatively, the files can be copied with `rsync`, with its `-a, --archive` option to preserve time-stamps, ownership, modes, etc. and its `-X, --xattrs` option to preserve the extended attributes such as the security labels used by AppArmor and SELinux:

```
sudo rsync -raX /var/ /var.new/
```

### Update the filesystem table

Configure the new filesystem to be used as a new mount-point for `/var` by adding the following line to `/etc/fstab`.  Note that `0` is used as the pass number (last field) so that the filesystem won’t be automatically checked (`fsck`) after a certain number of reboots.

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-var    /var    ext4  defaults  0 0
```

Since changing into single-user mode is not possible, reboot the computer to use this new volume as `/var`.

#### Remove temporary mount-point

After the machine has restarted, the new filesystem will be mounted on `/var` so the temporary mount-point can be safely removed:

```
sudo rmdir /var.new
```

### Recover disk space from the root filesystem

The old `/var` files will still be taking up space on the root partition but they are not easily accessible while another filesystem is mounted at `/var` (they are “masked” by the new filesystem using the `/var` directory as its mount-point). Use a temporary mount-point to mount the root filesystem so that contents of the original `/var` directory are available by an alternative path.

```
    sudo mkdir /old-root
    sudo mount /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-root /old-root/
    sudo rm -rf /old-root/var/*
    sudo umount /old-root/
    sudo rmdir /old-root/
```

Comment: Nice explanation of the options involved. However, you use `lvcreate` and `mkfs.ext4` without explaining what are or why are used. Maybe you can simply tell that is for making the new partition as they aren't the main topic of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @PhoneixS  I've edited the answer to make it clearer and provide additional contextual information.