# how to install package to a specific hard disk drive partition

Tags: apt

By default apt-get installs packages in the drive that the ubuntu installation resides on.
But can i install a package other than the ubuntu partition ?
If i can, how to do it ?

Comment: Without some *extremely* advanced skills in remapping various folders to external storage and partitions, it is not normal in Ubuntu-land to put everything into other partitions.  And the more partitions/disks you include in your setup the more points of failure you have where you run into single points of failure (extra partitions).

Comment: See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`.
  
It explains where things go.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to figure out how to do this as well.  I have read that you can only install on the default partition.  This is because installing on other partitions can cause viruses or unwanted things on your computer.  What I have done to get around this is to install the package on the default partition then add a script to the beggining of it that will move the files where you want the first time the program is started.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the software, you may be able to find it as a [portable application](http://portablelinuxapps.org/), which you could install wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you want this. If it's for space reasons, one viable approach would be to mount large directories (probably /bin or /usr, where many programs reside) in an extra partition. See e.g. this question: [How can I store /var on a separate partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39536/how-can-i-store-var-on-a-separate-partition) for how to do that.

Comment: yes, it is for space reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Another option beside the defunct link for another answer's "portable application" which seems to now correlate to the link below, which is a collection of single file AppImages, is to use the other portable package apps like Flatpak or Snap. With these you can symlink the dirs onto another partition.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/portable/files/64bit/

https://appimage.org/

https://flathub.org

https://snapcraft.io