# "No space left" during upgrade

Tags: upgrade, disk

I'm in the process of running the 12.04 upgrade (Kubuntu). My root partition is a bit small, but I cleared as much as I could after the upgrade told me it needed more space.

During "Installing the upgrades" it was doing something with 'nvidia_current' and ran out of space writing /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_current.ko

I have cleared some more space by deleting old logs, but the upgrade process sits there adding more dots to a long line. There is about 180MB free now, which seems to be going down slowly.

Will it ever continue or will a reboot continue the upgrade?

Comment: No restart needed my friend , just continue with Upgrade . If it still giving space issue then restart will make it clear :)

Comment: Not sure how I continue the upgrade. It just keeps adding ... in the log

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by selecting the best answer (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading the FAQ on asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It didn't look like it was going to do anything further, so I restarted. The new kernel didn't boot, so I went back to the old one. Various stuff was broken, including network.

Tried running

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and that said to run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

That seemed to finish off the set-up and I now have a working system again. Still need to test a few things, but generally looking good.

Since then I've moved /var to a different partition to avoid this issue in future as detailed on [How can I store /var on a separate partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39536/how-can-i-store-var-on-a-separate-partition)

Comment: cool , Actually update-manager can resume your upgrade and terminal way also can resume . glad to hear that you out of that issue . :)

Comment: No, often a partial upgrade will break the system EXACTLY as @steevc described and has to be fixed up manually.

Comment: Did that finish the upgrade...or did it give you back your working *pre-upgrade* version of the system? (`lsb_release -r` is usually an accurate way to find out what release version you're running.)

Comment: @Eliah, it finished the 12.04 upgrade