# Manage Snapshots

Tags: backup, lvm, snapshot

So Ubuntu supports [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm). This in turn supports creating and restoring snapshots of the hard drive. Coming from Windows, this is a highly useful feature for restoring the system to a previous point (In Windows called System Restore), also great for backups!

I would specifically like to schedule snapshots to be taken periodically (say every Sunday) and would also like an easy way to manage and delete snapshots. And of course, to restore back to a snapshot if need be.

How can I do this?

Comment: Linux is not windows and snapshots of the system are, IMO, not very useful. Personally I back up the home directory and any system files I manually edited. All the other information is available at any time in the repositories. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/424225/setting-up-lvm-snapshot-as-a-backup-restore-point-in-ubuntu and http://fritshoogland.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/using-lvm-snapshots-for-backup-and-restore-of-filesystems/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LVM is currently not usable for this.  The current snapshot implementation falls apart when you try to create multiple and/or long lived snapshots.  Supposedly there is a new snapshot implementation coming down the pike that may be able to handle this, but it isn't here yet.

Comment: One can use TimeShift till then, it supports snapshots