# Ubuntu ISO creation from running OS

Tags: 14.04, iso

Im just curious but is it possible to build a bootable iso of my running 14.04 OS?
Like if I could create an iso that upon running again would reinstall? I have to redo my system but I have so many files and shell scripts that I dont want to reinstall from fresh but reinstall the OS im using now.  Could this be possible?

Comment: So you would want to take a snapshot of your computer's current state so that you could restore that? Or load that exact state onto another computer.

Comment: @Toroidal Ya that's what I would like to be able to do

Comment: This would probably be also something useful you should look at as well as the question that this has been marked as duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/424225/setting-up-lvm-snapshot-as-a-backup-restore-point-in-ubuntu