# LVM Snapshot Tutorial on Ubuntu Server

Tags: 16.04, lvm

I'm looking for a good tutorial on making a LVM snapshot on Ubuntu Server. I can't find one that isn't way too in depth about what LVM is or I can't find one that is up to date. My ultimate goal is to learn how to make snapshots of my server with LVM so I can return to previous states if I need to.

Also I looked at the volume groups and logical volumes on a clean install of Ubuntu Server 16 in a VM. It looks like there is already an LVM. This is where I got confused.

Could somebody provide a link to a good tutorial for that? Am I completely misunderstanding what LVM is? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What is a snapshot?

snapshots are a facility which makes us able to create a new block device (like /dev/My-vg/snapshot_home ) which presents an exact copy of a logical volume frozen at some point in time. After we are done with what we are doing, we can simply remove the snapshot device.

**Important to note while creating a snapshot:**
While creating a snapshot we should consider enough disk space for our changes, if our changes makes snapshot device space full then it will be dropped and becomes unusable.

**When to use it?**
Some times we need to install an application or run a program we don't know what it's going to happens or in any situations that makes any changes to our files we can setup a snapshot device, if we were not happy with the change we can simply make everything same as the time we created our snapshot.

#### How to create a snapshot

To create a snapshot we can use a command like:

```
lvcreate -s -n  home_snap -L 1G /dev/My-vg/home
```

- `-s` is for snapshot
- `-n home_snap` is the name of our new logical volume (snapshot device)
- `L 1G` is the size of our snapshot, so it supports to 1GB of changes (remember the above important note).
- `/dev/mapper/my--vg-home` is the logical volume that I want to create a snapshot of.

then use `sudo lvs` to get a list of your logical volumes you should see your newly created snapshot device.

Note that you should have enough free space on your volume group to create a new snapshot.

sources: [1](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html), [2](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshotintro.html)