# How to keep ubuntu snaps on a separate partition?

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, snap

I am using 75 GB SSD partition as root and 1 TB HDD for /home and /data partition.
75 GB starts filling quite fast when I install android studio and other heavy IDEs.

I know that ubuntu snaps stores and mounts applications on /snap/ folder but the source folder is still under /var/lib/snapd. Is it possible to move snapd to a separate folder, maybe  within /data folder so that my root wont fill up.

One obvious solution that I can think of is keeping /var/ on a separate partition, but I don't know if that is a standard practice.

Answer (score 4):

In the past when disks were small it was very common to put /var (and indeed /usr) on another partition / disk. It's fallen out of favour among most, as default installs tend to put everything on one disk, and disks are large. However, with the advent of SSDs which were initially small, and got expensive very quickly if you went large, you sometimes need to split directories to separate disks.

So in short, yes, it's perfectly fine to move /var to another disk There is a simple guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/39542/612) which should get you started.