# Can I install snaps only in my home directory?

Tags: snap

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop with dual boot. When I initially installed it, I only assigned 30GB to the root partition, which has now proved to be insufficient. Looking over unnecessary things to delete I noticed that the /var/lib/snapd/snaps directory takes up a lot of space.

Why must these packages be in the root directory? Is there a way to keep all the snap related stuff in my home directory, which has way more space assigned to it? I am the only user in my Ubuntu system, so it doesn't really matter to install things between multiple users.

Edit: Ubuntu version is 22.04

Comment: In short, no. You could move them to a folder in your home partition and bind mount that to `/var/lib/snapd/snaps`, but it's probably quicker and easier to reinstall with one big partition or resize root.

Comment: Another option would be to steal a bit of your home and create a new `/var` partition and keep your snaps in that. Either way there's some repartitioning needed.

Comment: Here's a guide which may be useful. https://askubuntu.com/questions/39536/how-can-i-store-var-on-a-separate-partition/39542#39542